# Indentation not working properly for if-else statement in vscode for java

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image showing the indentation problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ998.png)

I am using vscode for programming in java and for auto-indentation, I am using "prettier". I have applied all the necessary settings in the preferences menu like "Format on Save" and "Default code formatter", but still vscode fails to indent properly the if-else statement as shown in the image. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [java prettier formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mwpb.java-prettier-formatter)

Comment: That did wonder!! Thanks a lot!